# nested columns in compass/sass

Tags: css, haml, sass, compass-sass

I've been studying compass and while it is a fun thing to play with and use, one thing bothers me(besides being unable to add padding as it wrecks the grid), how do I nest columns?

I want to be able to do what blueprint does: nest containers like say, I have a 24-column page divided in two(17 and 7 columns). In the right part of that page(the one with 7 columns), I want to divided some elements into two(2 and 5 columns).

I tried this:

```
#main
  +container

  #main-content
    +column(17)
    +box-padding(17, 10px)
    :margin
    :right 0

  #sidebar
    +column(7, true)
    +box-padding(7, 10px)
```

That's the code for the main page. The sidebar contains a list with some labels and input fields

```
li
  +container
  :margin
    :bottom 5px

label
  +column(2)
  :margin
    :right 0

input
  +column(5, true)
```

It *kinda* works, but inspecting the li in firebug shows that it's width is actually 950px as opposed to be just 270px since it is just 7 columns. I tried googling about nested columns but I can't seem to find any example in compass. I've also tried the wiki and the documentation to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think part of the problem (maybe the whole problem?) is that you've applied the `container` mixin to the `li`. That mixin defines the width as the value of `!blueprint_container_size` which, by default, has a value of `950px` (but can be overridden). Remove that and you should be okay. The container is meant to delineate the whole, not parts within the whole.

Comment: I've actually tried it without the container mixin but that makes it worse since the columns don't work anymore. Should there be a mixin I should be using instead of +container?

Comment: `+container` is the right mixin to use on `#main`, but since it defines the overall width of the body, it doesn't belong on the list item. Can you update your question with what happens when you remove the mixin from your `li`? I'm a little miffed that it doesn't work for you; I know that I've used it this way before.

Comment: i went ahead and just used float left and added widths to my label and  input fields but im also miffed that the column mixin isn't working for me. I'm pretty sure i will run in to this problem again sometime so I will update my question in awhile with your request.

Comment: Actually i just checked it again today and somehow it is working. WTH was wrong before? Anyway thanks for the help!